# Motherboard errors in work with memory

Tags: memory, motherboard, bsod

I have some problems with my motherboard.

Some time ago there was BSOD every month ion my Win7. I've checked memory and MemTest showed (from 10 to 120) errors. Next i checked this memory with others PC - and there were no errors. And when i checked motherboard with 100% good memory - i recevied MemTest errors again.

So as far as i understand there is problem with motherboard. Slots were cleaned from dust, capacitors seems to be ok, decreasing frequency (1600/1333/1033) - nothing helps. What can i do to fix this problem?

Motherboard - Gigabyte GA-H81M-D2V

Comment: Are you overclocking the CPU and are you absolutely sure that the memory chips are fully compatible with your motherboard?  Note that slowing down DRAM refresh rate can not help at all.

Comment: No, i haven't overclocked system ever. About compatibility - motherboard + this memory worked correctly near 2 years

Comment: Then we can easily conclude that there is a hardware problem, but clarifying it would require replacing some components such as the CPU, motherboard or power supply.  Although power supply problems rarely cause this kind of issue, it happens and since that is the simplest thing to replace for testing, that would be your next step.

Comment: Really odd, although the cpu is now the memory controller, unless you have very poor cooling, the most likely suspect is the motherboard. the motherboard provides the voltages still, could be you can investigate the ram voltages closer and try to find out more.  Bent socket pins are also a common cause of ram fails, and uneven pressure (vertical) heat sync , but it would be more rare for that to be a few errors more like total failure.  What memory test did you use? were you in an operating system at the time  ? (vrses just a simplified boot disk).

Comment: If you have verified the memory is actually functional then you should replace the CPU and motherboard as they are the only two compodents that could cause this problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

BIOS updating to actual version seems to be solve the problem. Thanks everyone for advices!